# Pdfdocument using Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I call .ttf font from Assets folder to my project  using  itextsharp Pdfdocument in xamarin forms ,Can any one help me please.

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTWO7.png)

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have some code that doesn't work?

Comment: So you want to use a font and with that font you want to create a pdf document